# Suppress line numbers in front of 'repeat' and 'until' keywords in algorithmic

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Test}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE
    \REPEAT
    \STATE state
    \STATE state
    \STATE state
    \UNTIL condition
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I get this result:

[image]

But I would prefer this result:

[image]

How can I achive this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) creates all of the necessary pseudocode macros at the start of the `algorithmic` environment. As such, it's not as easy to merely patch `\REPEAT` and/or `\UNTIL` in the "usual" way.

The following MWE inserts the patch after the `algorithmic` environment starts. The patch uses a "no step" `\item` in the form of `\ALC@it@nostep` rather than the default `\ALC@it`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{xpatch,letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ALC@it@nostep}{\item[]}% No-step algorithmic item
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\LetLtxMacro\oldalgorithmic\algorithmic
\LetLtxMacro\endoldalgorithmic\endalgorithmic
\renewenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]{%
  \oldalgorithmic[#1]%
  \xpatchcmd{\REPEAT}{\ALC@it}{\ALC@it@nostep}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\UNTIL}{\ALC@it}{\ALC@it@nostep}{}{}%
}{\endoldalgorithmic}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Test}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \REQUIRE
  \REPEAT
  \STATE state
  \STATE state
  \STATE state
  \UNTIL condition
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```